# Creating a Web Page in Google Sites through the GData API and the AtomEntry is always null

Tags: gdata

I'm using the same GDAta API code from https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/sites/dotnet/SitesAPIDemo.cs to programatically create web pages in Google Sites in C#.

The problem I'm getting is when I create a Web Page the page is created successfully in the site but the returned object (newEntry) is always null so I can't create any child pages with the returned information.

```
        SiteEntry entry = new SiteEntry();
        AtomCategory category = new AtomCategory(SitesService.WEBPAGE_TERM, SitesService.KIND_SCHEME);
        category.Label = "webpage";
        entry.Categories.Add(category);
        entry.Title.Text = title;
        entry.Content.Type = "xhtml";
        entry.Content.Content = html;
        entry.ExtensionElements.Add(makePageNameExtension(pageName));

        AtomEntry newEntry = null;
        try
        {
            //the newEntry below is always returned as null
            newEntry = service.Insert(new Uri(makeFeedUri("content")), entry);
        }
        catch (GDataRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ResponseString);
        }

        return newEntry;
```

Has anybody seen this problem before?

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to get into the source code of the SDK to fix this temporarily. This method seems to be the problem:

```
    public TEntry Insert<TEntry>(Uri feedUri, TEntry entry) where TEntry : AtomEntry
    {
        return this.Insert(feedUri, entry, null) as TEntry;
    }
```

I have changed this to return an AtomEntry rather than a TEntry and the object is no longer null:

```
    public AtomEntry Insert<TEntry>(Uri feedUri, TEntry entry) where TEntry : AtomEntry
    {
        return this.Insert(feedUri, entry, null);
    }
```